# Mockito - mocked class variable is null

Tags: android, mockk

I have created a sample project with Mockk and I am having a viewModel and a dependency class Repository

```
class DefaultUserRepository:UserRepository {

    val listOfUser =ArrayList<User>()

    override fun insertUser(user: User):User {
        listOfUser.add(user)
        return user
    }

    override fun deleteUser(user: User) {
        listOfUser.remove(user)
    }

    override fun updateUser(user: User) {
        //listOfUser.repl
    }

    override fun getAlltUser():ArrayList<User> {
       return listOfUser
    }

}
```

Viewmodel :-

```
class ViewModelTest {

    lateinit var repository: DefaultUserRepository

    lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel



    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        repository = spyk(DefaultUserRepository())
        viewModel = ViewModel(repository)

    }

    @Test
    fun `test insert user successful`(){

//        every { viewModel.insertUser(any()) } returns User(1,"abc","abc")
//        every { viewModel.getAllsers() } returns repository.listOfUser

        val user = User(1,"abc","abc")
        viewModel.insertUser(user)
        verify { viewModel.insertUser(user) }

        val user2 = User(2,"abc","abc")
        viewModel.insertUser(user2)
        verify { viewModel.insertUser(user) }

        val getAllUsers = viewModel.getAllsers()
        assertEquals(getAllUsers.size,2)

    }
}
```

The thing is when i debug my test, the listOfuser is showing null even after calling insert though my test passes. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation `@RelaxedMockk` means `mockk` would definitely ignore the functions with `Unit` return type.

So if u change the following in the test class :-|

```
 @RelaxedMockk  
 lateinit var repository: DefaultUserRepository
```

to

```
 @Mockk  
 lateinit var repository: DefaultUserRepository
```

then the test class would not pass saying

> No answer found for DefaultUserRepository.insert(..).

**Solution**

I would suggest to use `spyk(DefaultUserRepository())` for your case:-

```
lateinit var repository: DefaultUserRepository
....

@Before
fun setUp() {
    repository = spyk(DefaultUserRepository())
    viewModel = ViewModel(repository)
}
```

So `repository` instance would be real repository and now when u debug u would find that `listOfUser` is not null.

Comment: so i tried this but listOfUser is of size 0 even after inserting

Comment: now while you are debugging is the `listUser` still empty ? @Vibhuti

Comment: it is empty... i am getting size as 0

Comment: after inserting user ? @Vibhuti

Comment: i have updated the code. the test fails as getAllUsers.size is 0

Comment: please delete this line `every { viewModel.getAllsers() } returns ArrayList<User>()` its 0 because u instructed mockk to return empty arraylist @Vibhuti

Comment: so even after u add an user it will always return an empty list @Vibhuti

Comment: so what do u want to achieve ? Not getting.. Please check the 3rd last comment @Vibhuti

Comment: i want to check if the user was inserted properly